# How can I find the root cause of nonpaged pool memory leak from pool tag PdcA called by umpdc.dll?

Tags: windows, audio, memory, drivers, memory-leaks

I have a nonpaged pool memory leak that grows consistently with about 80 allocations per second, each 200 bytes. So it is about 16kB per second or 58MB / hour, 1.4GB/day.

I have run poolmon.exe and sorted by bytes and can see that pool tag PdcA ha consistent positive change of nonpaged memory about 80,000 bytes per 5 second refresh.

I ran xperf and analyzed the pool.etl file in Windows Performance Analyzer and can see that the stack shows umpdc.dll!PdcpAlpcCallback being responsible for the growth with impacting size matching the growth rate seen in poolmon.exe (see attached screenshot). [WPA Screenshot showing 160kB increase in 10 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQeAo.png)

I also turned on the nonpaged memory column in the task manager details tab and saw about 600 MB of nonpaged memory associated with audiodg.exe (poolmon.exe shows about 6.5GB associated with PdcA). When I killed audiodg.exe from task manager, I saw a few MB of negative change to the PdcA nonpaged pool bytes, and the continuous 80KB/5 second growth stopped and went to 0, but about 6.5GB of memory is still unfreed in PdcA.

I'm sure a restart will free that 6.5GB, and it seems clear that audiodg.exe is the culprit, but I understand that is a standard windows component. The call stack in pool.etl doesn't show anything specific that is the root cause. And it doesn't even show audiodg.exe, but I know that to be the cause because killing that process stopped the memory growth immediately. I'm guessing audiodg.exe set up the callback that is being executed (umpdc.dll!PdcpAlpcCallback)? How can one find out what other software (if any) triggered audiodg.exe to set up that callback in the first place? Why doesn't more information show in the call stack in WPA?

How Can I find out how to stop this from continuing without disabling windows audio support that audiodg.exe provides? I don't have any audio devices attached other than plug and play hdmi monitor with built in speakers. I am not running any audio specific software other than an occasional web browser with a video that plays audio.

I am running Windows 10 version 20H2 build 19042.804

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the memory leak. I still don't know how to systematically find the cause in general, but in my case I noticed that if I looked at total cpu time in the details tab of Task Manager for audiodg.exe was the same as time since boot after a fresh reboot (i.e. constantly using cpu from startup) even though I hadn't launched any programs or even logged in to the computer yet. This gave me the idea to look at startup programs that are launching automatically. I noticed two audio related programs were enabled in startup: Skype and Spotify. I never have used these and don't even know when I would have installed them, but they were part of the startup programs anyway.

I disabled the startup of both of these and restarted the computer and after waiting a few minutes I saw 0 cpu usage for audiodg.exe and nonpaged pool of only 14K that was not growing. I then reenabled both of these in startup and rebooted and found significant cpu and nonpaged memory of over 1MB within a few minutes of startup in audiodg.exe. I don't know for sure which of these was the issue, but I don't need either so I uninstalled both and have not seen any problem with audiodg.exe using/leaking memory since then. I'll post again if it comes back, but if not, you can assume this took care of it.

I didn't bother to diagnose which of the two apps was the problem since I don't need either of them.

So, lesson to learn from this is that if poolmon.exe and the other tools mentioned in my original post point to a problem with audiodg.exe, it makes sense to look for any applications that use audio and try booting without startup enabled for those to see if the problem goes away as it did for me. Or disable all startup apps in general and reenable one at a time between restarts to see which might be the problem.

UPDATE: 05/13/2021
I was a bit hasty in concluding that the problem was taken care of by removing skype and spotify. After a few days I saw the same problem again and noticed that there was another audio related application that was automatically starting at login. Thermaltake light / fan control software was also set up to monitor audio for purposes of syncing lighting effects. I used [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for Windows from Sysinternals to figure out that Start_TTRGBPlus.bat was starting TT RGB Plus.exe

After disabling startup of that app, I have now had stable nonpaged memory for about a week without restarting.